# Display contents of a remote html file which needs authorization

Tags: swift, macos, webview

I'm on macOS 10.13.3 with Xcode 9.2 and I want to display the contents of a html file which is located on a server.
I want to display these contents in a normal WebView.
I could simply do that with

```
let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/file.html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        releaseNotesWebView.mainFrame.load(request)
```

But the server requires authorization. How can I add authorization infos to the request so that I can access the file and display the contents? Do I need a complete Session Configuration with `URLSession` or is there an easier way to get access? Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT:

For me it seems to work with the following code

```
let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/file.html")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let user = "username"
        let pwd = "password"
        let userPasswordData = "\(user):\(pwd)".data(using: .utf8)
        let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        releaseNotesWebView.mainFrame.load(request)
```

However the message "File Not Found" is displayed, in the webView. But I'm sure I entered it correctly. But I think I can figure it out.

EDIT2: OK, it works. Somehow the html file was corrupted. I used an other and now all is fine.

Comment: which authorization server is require? If it is some Header field, then you can add it to your request like `request.addValue("your_header_filed_value", forHTTPHeaderField: "YOUR_HEADER_FIELD_KEY")`

Comment: Yes, this was the right approach. I edited the code. Thank you!